# No module named 'PyPDF2' when is importing

Tags: python, pypdf

I have an error with import PyPDF2 (No module named). I tried to install for Python ver. 2, also don't work. I suppose that problem maybe connected with path of install module, but I can't change it... or with version Python, because in documentation said about ver 3.2-3.5

https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/About%20PyPDF2.html

cmd

C:\Users\Xiaomi>pip3 install PyPDF2
Requirement already satisfied: PyPDF2 in c:\users\xiaomi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (1.26.0)

C:\Users\Xiaomi>py
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

> > > import PyPDF2
> > > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'

> > > import sys
> > > print(sys.path)
> > > ['', 'C:\Users\Xiaomi\Anaconda3\python37.zip', 'C:\Users\Xiaomi\Anaconda3\DLLs', 'C:\Users\Xiaomi\Anaconda3\lib', 'C:\Users\Xiaomi\Anaconda3', 'C:\Users\Xiaomi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages', 'C:\Users\Xiaomi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\Users\Xiaomi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\Users\Xiaomi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin']

Comment: Doesn't work ver.3.5 python

C:\Users\Xiaomi>py -3.5
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

>>> import PyPDF2

ImportError: No module named 'PyPDF2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are installing PyPDF2 in a different directory from your working directory.
You need to install it in the same directory.

Comment: Yes, to chance path: 


import os
os.chdir(path)

Answer (score 1):

Use pyPDF4, pyPDF2 doesn't seem like it's supported anymore

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not a lot of info but switching to PyPDF4 finally solved my PyPDF problem +1